# How can I detect the amount of memory slots I have?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, memory, hardware-detection

I know that there used to be a Corsair memory detection tool, but I can no longer find it. I didn't find anything when searching Google.

I would like to scan my machine to know a few things:

1. How many memory slots I have on my motherboard.
2. The stats per memory stick I have installed in my machine (i.e. speed and size of each stick)
3. The maximum allowable size and speed per slot (i.e. my motherboard can manage 4GB per slot, at DDR27600 - if that is even a speed, been a while since I upgraded :|)

I am using Windows XP and 7. Any suggestions?

Comment: Crucial has a scanner...http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/index.aspx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Try Speccy Free Edition](http://www.piriform.com/speccy/download)

.

[image]

Comment: +1 Actually shows information about available RAM slots unlike some options below.

Answer (score 83):

How about going by command-line without any third party installer?

`wmic MEMORYCHIP get banklabel, capacity, caption, devicelocator, partnumber`

gives you something like this

```
BankLabel  Capacity    Caption          DeviceLocator   PartNumber
BANK 2     4294967296  Physical Memory  ChannelB-DIMM0  xxxxxxxxxx-PB
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know this was possible!

Comment: :) WMI is a safe and powerful window to Windows.

Comment: Cool! Can this tool list also the memory slots that are _not_ used?

Comment: For more memory info type first just `wmic` -> that will open wmic console, and afterwards type `memorychip` which will print all memory info in one big scrollable line.

Comment: This does not report empty slots :-(

Comment: @SamB `wmic MEMORYCHIP get memorydevices` will show total memory slots available

Comment: @SteveZhan: Unfortunately, `wmic MEMORYCHIP get memorydevices` just gives an `Invalid query` error here :-(

Comment: @SamB try `wmic MEMPHYSICAL get MemoryDevices`

Comment: @icl7126 when i run this `wmic MEMPHYSICAL get MemoryDevices` i get `MemoryDevices
2
`  does this mean i have 2 slots?

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar I'm not sure, but based on the comments above I would say it means you have 2 memory slots in use, but you can have other two empty. Most of the notebooks has 2 memory slots.

Comment: no my laptop contains only one ram ,also  task manager & cpu-z shows that i have 2 memory slots . take a look at my                   :https://superuser.com/questions/1272057/ram-upgrading-tips             i can't find second slot like in the image

Answer (score 31):

To answer question (1) using WMIC:

```
wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity,MemoryDevices
```

produces something like this:

```
MaxCapacity  MemoryDevices
16777216     2
```

Comment: This should be the right answer ... Thank you!

Comment: What units is the MaxCapacity in? Is that 16GB?

Comment: It's kilobytes. I answered here: https://superuser.com/a/1217045/241250

Comment: Should I take that maxCapacity as a report of current reality, or as a theoretical maximum? Right now I have 16GB RAM, and my MaxCapacity shows as 16GB. Is it telling me the RAM I have now, or is it telling me I can't upgrade any further because 16GB is the maximum my laptop can take? Does anybody see a MaxCapacity value _above_ their current actual installed RAM? Thanks

Answer (score 28):

**[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)** offers detailed information about RAM slots, timings, XMP profiles, etc. As for max supported you normally will have to look up the limits imposed by your northbridge.

[image]

Comment: CPU-z really is the best out there, and it will suite your needs wonderfully.

Comment: How can I tell how many slots there are, and how many are in use?

Comment: The SPD tab shows individual slot details.

Comment: Readings of memory clock (DRam Freq) in CPUZ is half or less than half for DDR2 or higher.

Comment: I like CPU-Z however, DO NOT RUN THIS ON A PRODUCTION SERVER. I just learned this the hard way. My server stopped responding and required a reboot. Management was not pleased.

Comment: +1 because is the only application that is for free (optional donation)

Answer (score 11):

For anyone using Windows 10, you can just open Task Manager -> Performance Tab -> Click Memory and it will tell you slots used out of total available.

Answer (score 9):

What about PowerShell, Let's check this out:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory | fl BankLabel, Capacity, `
  DeviceLocator, PartNumber, SerialNumber, PositionInRow, Speed, Tag
```

Answer (score 3):

To find total RAM slots are in a server use the below in a command prompt:

```
wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices
```

To find how much RAM is present in the server use the following:

```
wmic MEMORYCHIP get banklabel, capacity, caption, devicelocator, partnumber
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions above truly present an accurate description of physical memory configurations including empty slots, particularly with servers running Windows due to the lack of SPD info (which most of the reporting programs freely available rely on).  The *ONLY* solution I have found that does not cost s-tons is Belarc Advisor.  It doesn't have a nice real-time interface like Speccy but the text report is mucho helpful.  Just look at this, does not get any more clear:

```
Memory Modules 
Slot 'DIMM_A1 ' has 16384 MB (serial number 0D561***)
Slot 'DIMM_A2 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_A3 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_A4 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_A5 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_A6 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_B1 ' has 16384 MB (serial number 0D561***)
Slot 'DIMM_B2 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_B3 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_B4 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_B5 ' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM_B6 ' is Empty
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but I needed to see what memory was installed on my server and what slots were open. I don't have physical access, only RD. I like and use Speccy a lot but it was not able to tell me the slots used vs open on this particular server. Belarc Adv did that for me. Between BA and SIW below (which also was helpful for the details on the exact memory currently installed) I have a handle on what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [System Information for Windows](https://www.gtopala.com/) (SIW) for years and found it a fantastic toolkit.  Not only does it show number of memory slots, it shows what's in them, the maximum capacity, the manufacturer, part number, voltage etc etc

That's just the tip of the iceberg - you can find out software licence keys (Windows, Office and others), certain passwords, CPU information, laptop battery wear, hard drive temperatures, the list is endless!  (I've used it for years and must have used a fraction of it's features.)

Not only that - there's no install, it's just a 2MB executable so ideal for putting on a USB drive for PC diagnostics.

[image: System Information for Windows]

Unfortunately, the free home version [has been discontinued](https://www.gtopala.com/download/), and even if you can find it it doesn't work on Windows 10. I guess Gabriel Topala finally wanted more than the "Buy me a coffee" option, but to be fair he's certainly earned it!

Comment: I know this is an old post but I needed to see what memory was installed on my server and what slots were open. I don't have physical access, only RD. SIW (trial) was helpful for the details on the exact memory currently installed including model, Serial, Capacity, speed, etc (all crucial details when ordering more ram). It didn't indicate empty slots however (maybe due to trial status). For that information Belarc Advisor above was good: it indicated 2 slots of n were being used. Now I know that I can get n-2 more ram for this machine.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for Windows users is to open the Windows Task Manager.

1. Press the Windows key, type Task Manager, and then press Enter.
2. In the window that appears, click the Performance tab, then select Memory.
3. In the lower-right corner, the number of slots is displayed in the Slots used: section.

You can also use some apps or examine the motherboard. This post will show you these two methods: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001405.htm

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can just :

1. Open the task manager (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd> Key)
2. Click on the Performance Tab
3. Select The Memory Option
4. Information of the memory will be available (including information about available slots, used and unused).

Comment: I'm guessing that wasn't available on Windows XP or 7.

Comment: oh kk cool but the terminal could still be of help

Comment: I guess, you meant Ctrl + SHIFT + Escape key combination.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for Windows users is to open the Windows Task Manager.

Press the Windows key, type Task Manager, and then press Enter.
In the window that appears, click the Performance tab (A), then select Memory (B).
In the lower-right corner, the number of slots is displayed in the Slots used: section (C).

Comment: (1) This seems to duplicate a couple of previous answers.  (2) What's this about "A", "B" and "C"?  Did you mean to include a picture?  (3) Please specify what version of Windows you are talking about.  This does not work on all versions. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.