# Command "wmic memphysical get maxcapacity" gives wrong number

Tags: windows-7, wmic

I have been using my laptop with 16G (8gx2) memory for a long time, I can use all of 16G memory without any problem, but ran `wmic memphysical get maxcapacity` today shows however 8388608 (8G), apparently wrong, what's wrong with the command? More importantly, is there a way to get the right number?

Comment: WMI's 'MaxCapacity' is "Maximum memory size (in bytes) installable for this particular memory array." [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394348(v=vs.85).aspx), not the size of the currently installed RAM. See `wmic Memorychip`. :)

Comment: As I can use 16G, should the "maximum memory size installable" not be 16777216 at least?

Answer (score 6):

MaxCapacity is in kilobytes.

[Here is the source documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394348(v=vs.85).aspx).

The documentation is confusing but this is what I think.

**Documentation**

It says that MaxCapacity is:

> Maximum memory size (in bytes) installable for this particular memory array. If the size is unknown, the property is given a value of 0 (zero).

However, MaxCapacity also has a DEPRECATED qualifier, which is defined like so:

> Deprecated
>
> Data type: CIM_BOOLEAN
>
> Applies to: properties, classes
>
> Indicates the property has been superseded by another property.

MaxCapacityEx has the same definition:

> Maximum memory size (in bytes) installable for this particular memory array. If the size is unknown, the property is given a value of 0 (zero).

But also specifies that the units are

> Units ("kilobytes")

**Use Case**

When I use the command `wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity`, I get the result `16777216`.

1677216 bytes is 16 Mb

1677216 kilobytes is 16 Gb

16 Mb just doesn't make any sense. Therefore, it's probably returning kilobytes.

**Your Max Capacity per slot**

8388608 kilobytes is 8 Gb

Use the command `wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices` to see the Maximum Capacity for each slot and the number of slots you have on your motherboard.

*My output is*:

```
MaxCapacity  MemoryDevices
16777216     2
```