# Can I tell whether a computer has 1x16 GB memory chip or 2x8 GB chips without opening it up?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have an extra 8 GB of memory on one chip left over from a team update.  I know it'd fit inside a co-worker's laptop, but she currently has 16 GB and her computer only has two slots.

She's extremely busy, and our team lead, and I don't want to take apart her computer just to find I can't do anything.  I'd like to have her look up what she already has before I raise her hopes.  She's on Window's 10.

Comment: A simple hardware reporting tool like hwinfo should report the memory module specifics, telling you if it's one or two modules.

Comment: Who is downvoting valid answers??

Comment: @Stese it could be that the link only answers to external tools are triggering off the review queues. The question asks for a solution, and the answers in this case are likely to group around external tools which can lead to more scrutiny as the answers pass through the review queue. If there were a Windows 10 command line or UI based answer it would sail through.

Comment: @Stese - Somebody who disagrees that they are quality helpful answers.  Duplicate questions exist, but my major issue, system properties displays the requested information.  So the software recommendations are not necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/606318/how-to-find-the-ram-type-in-command-prompt/1188905#1188905

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two better answers:

1) Go to the dos command line ("cmd") and enter: "wmic memorychip list full"
[image]

2) Task Manager, Performance, "Slots used" (bottom right).

[image]

Comment: please stop calling it "DOS" because it has nothing to do with DOS apart from many borrowed commands during the transition from DOS to Windows. cmd commands are different from DOS and it can also run tools that DOS can't. [Are the Command Prompt and MS-DOS the same thing?](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to answer provided by Dark Matter I found a command line tool.

You can run the cmds natively in Command Prompt.

Or you can run the cmds as follows in Powershell.

---

## Powershell

PS >

```
cmd.exe /c "wmic MEMPHYSICAL get MemoryDevices, MaxCapacity"

cmd.exe /c "wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel, DeviceLocator, Capacity, Speed, PartNumber"
```

[image]

---

## Command Prompt

Command:  **`wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel, DeviceLocator, Capacity, Speed, PartNumber`**

> C:>wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel, DeviceLocator, Capacity, Speed,
> PartNumber
>
> BankLabel  Capacity    DeviceLocator        PartNumber        Speed
>
> ChannelA   8589934592  Bottom-Slot 1(left)  M471A1K43BB1-CRC  2133
>
> C:>

I can tell that I have 8 GB in 1 slot... `8589934592 bytes = (8589934592 / 1,073,741,824) = 8 GB`

BankLabel column will tell you which slots the RAM chips are installed in. Capacity columns will tell you that how large each module is expressed in bytes. DeviceLocator is another entity to tell which slots the RAM chips are installed in.  The PartNumber is the exact part you have installed; You can look up this part number online at your favorite parts store (Amazon.com, Newegg.com, etc), and find more specs there.

Command: **`wmic memorychip list full`** -- For full list of memorychip data fields

Lots more commands found here: [TechNet Blogs: Useful WMIC Queries](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries/)

---

Furthermore, use the following command to display the Number of slots you have on your motherboard and the Capacity for each slot.

Command:  **`wmic MEMPHYSICAL get MemoryDevices, MaxCapacity`**

> C:>wmic memphysical get MemoryDevices, MaxCapacity
>
> MaxCapacity  MemoryDevices
>
> 33554432     2
>
> C:>

MaxCapacity is in kilobytes, so on my computer it is 32 GB max capacity per slot... `33554432 / 1,048,576= 32`.  That is 64 GB total max capacity.

Reference: [Microsoft Docs: win32-physicalmemoryarray](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-physicalmemoryarray)

Credit: [How can I detect the amount of memory slots I have?](https://superuser.com/questions/331282/how-can-i-detect-the-amount-of-memory-slots-i-have)

Credit: [Command "wmic memphysical get maxcapacity" gives wrong number](https://superuser.com/questions/973417/command-wmic-memphysical-get-maxcapacity-gives-wrong-number)

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is other ways but, there is a program called aida64(formerly everest or something). You can use it. Here is your link https://www.aida64.com/downloads

Comment: Also, You can see the frequences etc. to know whether they will work properly or not

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, providing value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a very simple software called CPUID - https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/787629)

Comment: @JasonAller I can vouch for this free program. Should I provide a new answer, with a screenshot with some red freehand circles?

Comment: Neeraj, welcome to Super User.  The problem with the answer is that it doesn't really address the "how" in the question, it just points to a product.  There's good guidance [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) on how to recommend software in an answer.  @JohnDvorak, sure you could post a new answer, but consider helping a new user by editing this one to demonstrate how to do it.  :-)

Answer (score -2):

Some websites have plugins that allow you to discern this. One such is Crucial.  http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/memory-info

Run the advice tool on her machine.