# Interpretation of wmic memphysical query output values

Tags: memory, wmic

I ran this command in the command prompt and was wondering if I was interpreting the output of the command correctly.

The command goes as follows:

```
wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices
```

The output of the command was:

```
MaxCapacity MemoryDevices
33445521                2
```

So that means there are at least two physical slots for RAM cards, and the total sum of their memory can be 32 GB? I am wondering if that is right.

References:

- [Question 1](https://superuser.com/questions/973417/command-wmic-memphysical-get-maxcapacity-gives-wrong-number)

Comment: `MemoryCapacity` = wrong query, do you mean `MaxCapacity` like in the other question?

Comment: I was just about to fix my question. I was just doing more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions look to be half-correct. As it can be found in the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemoryarray):

- `MaxCapacity`:

> Use the **MaxCapacityEx** property instead.
>
> This value comes from the **Maximum Capacity** member of the **Physical Memory Array** structure in the SMBIOS information.

`MaxCapacityEx`:

> Maximum memory size (in kilobytes) installable for this particular
> memory array. If the size is unknown, the property is given a value of
> 0 (zero).
>
> This value comes from the **Extended Maximum Capacity** member of the
> **Physical Memory Array** structure in the SMBIOS information.

So we have maximum installable size (in kB) of the memory array for the device (per slot). If I understood you correctly, you meant it's the total sum of both slots, but it's for one.

---

- `MemoryDevices`:

> Number of physical slots or sockets available in this memory array.
>
> This value comes from the **Number of Memory Devices** member of the **Physical Memory Array** structure in the SMBIOS information.

And here we have number of available slots for memory in the array for the device.

---

Even more info can be found in SMBIOS [documentation](https://dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.2.0.pdf).