# RAM upgrading tips

Tags: laptop, memory, speed, voltage

[image: here it shows that i have two memory slot]

I am going to increase RAM size by add another DIMM in the 2<sup>nd</sup> slot of my motherboard. My concern is how to buy RAM online with exact voltage, speed, single or dual channel.

Will my mother board support both single channel & dual channel RAM?

If I cannot find second slot in my laptop, where would it be?

My laptop is an Lenovo E-4325,AMD A4 4300 HD Graphic processor. I cannot find the motherboard details.

Comment: 1. Your laptop might not have  two sockets for SoDIMMs. LKook at a manual on the Lenovo website.  2. Single or dual: look in the manual once found.  3. Speed and voltage settings: look in the manual or run something like CPU-z. (assuming windows, no OS was specified in your question).

Comment: i found speed and voltage by cpu-z ,i use windows 10.i cant get manual for my motherboard

Comment: This manual?https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/e4325_ug_en_20130312.pdf

Comment: i doesnt contain anything about 2nd slot

Comment: It does, See page 30. If there already is one first remove the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will my mother board support both single channel & dual channel RAM?

Checking page 30 of [the manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/e4325_ug_en_20130312.pdf) as linked to by @darius:

It consistently mentioned **the** memory slot. It never mentions plurals.
Your laptop only has one physical memory slot.

[image: Page 30]

> If I cannot find second slot in my laptop, where would it be?

It is not there.

> Will my mother board support both single channel & dual channel RAM?

No. It needs at least two memory sockets for dual channel mode.
as to the term 'Dual channel RAM'; that does not exist. What is often sold as Dual channel memory are two identical SoDIMM's. The SoDIMM itself is not special or in any way different from normal triple, quad or single channel memory SoDIMM's.

Comment: but my task manager says it has two slots

Comment: What does it say precisely? Two physical present slots? A chipset capable of two or more slots? (onlyu one of which may be present).  One slot with a regular dual **rank** memory module? (that is one physical memory module acting as two independant models in one slot.) ... ?

Comment: but how could it be possible.it says "1 of 2 " what does that mean

Comment: I suspect that it reads the chipsets capability. As in: The CPU is capable of driving two independant channels. Not 'the actual motherboard builder implemented it this way'. it is hard to tyest that for me though since I only got a 2/2 filled laptop (and 4/4, and 6/6 desktop).

Comment: so it means i cant add another RAM

Comment: As I read it you may be able to increase memory by adding a bigger SoDIMM. But before you do that check what the maximum that the laptops supports is. There is a max in the memory controller (these days in the CPU), a test official max per module (sometimes bigger works but was not tested when the laptop came out) and a total max of max working SoDIMM size times number of sockets.

Comment: If it help, most memory manufacturers have sites like this: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/lenovo-e4325   (Which shows a max of 4GiB per SoSIMM for an E4325). Also note that 4GiB is rather large for DDR2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM).

Comment: i cant find whether my RAM in single or dual channel?

Comment: older RAM isn't static  does it support static RAM?

Comment: Re "I can't find whether my RAM in single or dual channel?". For the memory modules themselfes there is no difference between, single, dual, tripple or quad channel memory. The only way is in how the memory controller accesses the memory."

Comment: Re "older RAM isn't static". Generally static RAM is only used for caching. E.g. 256KiB cache made from SRAM chips on a 486 board. Everything since the pentium ERA tend to use SDRAM, SDRAM in double data rate mode (DDR), DDR2, DDR3, DDR4, ... Not static memory.

Comment: so i could buy any channel static RAM,right?

Comment: You cannot buy **static** RAM for use as main computer memory. You buy regular SoDIMMs (small outline synchronious DRAM) with the right DDRx version. Any of those will do for a single memory socket.

Comment: i see some space is used as hardware reserrved memory  (due to installed RAM was in an unsupported config) . so how can i find corrrect rRRAM

Answer (score 1):

I see you have already been linked the manual for the laptop. If this was not the case you can use `wmic bios get serialnumber` which will return your laptops serial number which you can then put into most manufacturers websites to get exact specifications and support for your specific product. I have recently learned that this command <strike>DOES NOT work with servers</strike> only works with OEM devices, so anyone reading should note that.

Looking at the diagram from the manual, it looks to me like you have two slots, but on top of eachother as opposed to adjacent. Here's a picture of what I mean, in any case it should be straightforward to open the laptop up and check. http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Upgrade-Laptop-RAM.png

I would think that armed with the serial number, you can check specs on the manufacturers website, and checking for dimm slots is straightforward. Once you know you're buying the right thing, installing is as easy as playing with lego.

Another thing to note are that RAM supposedly works better when you have 2 same brand (preferably same batch) sticks. So that's something to think about, although i've never thrown away decent RAM on behalf of it.

Hope some of this was helpful!

Comment: my Laptop is government gifted so RAM doesnt have any name on it . some  are help full i found that my RAM is !600 mhz low voltage DDR3

Comment: my RAM slot has only one slot like in the image but where is the other one?

Comment: Make sure you get a second stick to match DDR3 low voltage so! 

Some laptops allow you to mount two cards on top of each other like in the picture https://i.imgur.com/XZWI6au.png

If you're looking at the slot and this doesn't seem to be the case then it just doesn't exist i'm afraid!

Comment: i ll take a look at it .thank you all for the efforts .contact you guys later

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar how did this go for you? Was either answer good enough to be accepted?

Comment: yes both answer were useful .but there is no second slot for ram :(

Comment: That's a shame! You can try and buy a bigger single stick perhaps? Although it's worth looking into the fact that one 8GB stick isn't necessarily as fast as two 4GB sticks due to parallelisation etc.

Comment: yeah .are you cse engg.

Comment: I'm currently undergoing a research project and once i'm finished that I will have a Bachelors in Computer Science.

Comment: best of luck to you.i  am also cse engg 2nd year

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70108/discussion-between-jasinth-premkumar-and-ciaran-mckenzie).